# Store System.Decimal in Lucene.Net

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I want to store [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/364x0z75.aspx) type in [`NumericField`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d5/d8e/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_documents_1_1_numeric_field.html) field.

I do not want to store it as text.

However `NumericField.SetLongValue` is the biggest accuracy I can save out-of-the-box.

Should I implement my own `TokenStream` class to save `Decimal` values into Lucene index, or there is an alternative solution ?

Thanks

Comment: *Why* don't you want to store it as text, though? In the case of Decimal, precision is not an issue, so what else? Performance? Storage requirements? Lucene's `NumericField` has separate semantics for filtering and sorting. If you need those, using a custom `TokenStream` wouldn't help. If you *don't* need those, using a `NumericField` doesn't seem preferable to using text.

Comment: @Jeroen, I want to use range queries and have good performance, thanks

Comment: In that case, I think you're looking at extending Lucene to integrate support for `Decimal` in its `NumericRangeQuery`, which is quite a bit of work -- just storing new tokens won't cut it. An alternative would be to code the `Decimal` into multiple fields and range on those, but that requires client support.